# Potential client wants to pay in free stuff not money, how should I respond?

Tags: salary, freelancing

A potential client wants me to design promotional material for an event. However, in their initial solicitation, they said they would pay me with a free pass to their event which they claim is "$X value".

I am only interested in this work if I get compensated adequately in money. Not only does their "$X value" not leave much room for negotiating based on how much work it will take (it's not like they can give me 1.5 passes for instance), but I would not have gone to this event anyway, so to me it is $0 value.

I would like to say something like:

> I'm interested in the offer but I only work for money, not "$X value" items. Also, I will propose you a pricing after we discuss the project and I can gauge how much work it will be for me.

How can I say this politely? Or should I just decline the offer outright?

---

[How to deal with a company that wants to pay you with items instead of money?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/52955/13860) is very similar but not very relevant to me, since it concerns a situation where the work has already been done.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38605/discussion-on-question-by-superbest-potential-client-wants-to-pay-in-free-stuff).

Comment: If the potential client is naïve enough to think that the travel, and other expenses you would incur by using their "free pass" are irrelevant, they are probably not people you would want to attempt to do business with, unless you shared their views on economics (and from the question, you don't share them).

Comment: The "free" ticket that you don't want has even less than $0 value to you since you'll have to book it as income and pay taxes on it so you'd actually end up paying your own cash for it.

Comment: Are the clients corporate commercial, or say a charity, or other not for profit?

Comment: Watch this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVkLVRt6c1U)

Comment: You're doing it for the exposure, right? http://theoatmeal.com/comics/exposure

Comment: Free stuff is usually a bad deal, they are unlikely to start paying in the future, if they get the milk for free now.

Comment: @Johnny - You are of course correct that he "might" be in that situation, but the "value" of the "free pass" is not necessarily fixed. In fact, if the pass says "complementary" or "free" printed on it, then it could be argued that the value of it is $0. In any case, events give away plenty of tickets and sell many at a discount. In fact many events don't sell any tickets at full "face value". If he would accept the offer and not actually need the ticket, he could sell the ticket (even well below "face value") and claim the proceeds as income. Or, he could just donate the ticket --->

Comment: @Johnny ... to a charity. But it does seem to be a big hassle to me. If it was me, and I was inclined to accept the offer but I saw no real value in the ticket, I would decline the ticket and either 1) try to find something else they could offer (perhaps a piece of office equipment...)  or 2) just do it for free, for the exposure. A lot depends on "who" this company is, or could be in the future.

Comment: If they truly believe that the ticket is worth `$X` they should be able to find a way to convert it to `$X` and then give you the money, right? That is what "WORTH" means right? If they are not confident they can make the conversion, then clearly it is worth LESS than `$X` by their own valuation.

Comment: This may actually be illegal in some countries, as doing business with barter circumvents things like VAT.

Comment: Unless you're desperate, just decline. You'll probably get a lot of this sort of stuff in your career. You learn to filter it pretty quickly.

Comment: Valued at http://www.27bslash6.com/overdue.html

Comment: In the UK there are aslo the [Truck Acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truck_Acts) that that aim to prevent employers paying employees in goods

Comment: I would seriously consider not doing business with this client because there is a good change that no matter how clear you make it, that they will later try and pay you in gum or something equally useless. Just stay away from these kinds of clients... it isn't worth the hassle.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

I'd respond with something similar to:

> Thank you for your inquiry.  While I'm unable to accept a ticket to your event as payment for services I'm happy to provide a quote for you and a payment plan once we've discussed the project requirements. Let me know when you'd like to meet or call regarding this project.

Comment: Glad to see this answer accepted; It's highly professional and assumes good intentions. It's not devaluing the initial offer and it segues very nicely into discussing the requirements, which might very well get your foot in the door.

Comment: I now know what segue means.

Comment: I prefer clearness to politeness: “I only take money.”

Comment: "unwilling", not "unable"

Comment: @Anko, "I'm unable to accept a ticket to your event as payment" seems completely clear to me...

Comment: I'd suggest that anyone who uses this answer rephrase it to fit their personality and business needs. I don't believe that it should be used as-is for everyone for every similar purpose, individual variation is expected.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam While that may be true in many cases, the purpose of the sentence is to communicate a business requirement. If my customers read "unwilling" they might wonder if it was a personal issue with them, or if I was signaling that there is room for negotiation. Communication is the key, though, so make sure the message you're sending communicates your point. Depending on your clients that indeed may be "unwilling" rather than "unable".

Comment: Unable is simply logically wrong, even if you have a very strict personal policy that you have no intention of ever violating. Agreed that something stronger/clearer than "unwilling" might be necessary to communicate that though.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I understand your point, which is based on the literal definition of the word, and the concept that your customers and clients require that level and style of communication.  My customers are different than yours, and my business style is different.  The best way to communicate my business requirements to my customers is to use the word "unable." I don't doubt that you have different requirements and customers, and that the best way for you might be a different word.  I hope you understand that there is no single objectively perfect version for everyone and every situation.

Comment: You could even quite appropriately add "Unfortunately a ticket to your event won't enable me to cover my business/personal expenses"

Comment: @AdamDavis Obviously how you communicate with your own contacts is primarily a personal matter for you and them, but it's sad that you find it necessary to misuse language in order to communicate. Personally I have suppliers use this with me quite frequently and I find it very frustrating that they choose to exaggerate like this.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam *"...it's sad that you... misuse language..."* I appreciate your perspective, but this comment thread is already too off-topic and lengthy to go into this discussion further.  If you post a question about the purpose and use of language in communication  to the appropriate stackexchange site I'd be happy to expand on my perspective.

Comment: For the record, I accepted this answer because it (1) doesn't say anything that could be construed as rude and harm my reputation (2) provides a nice example that I can base my actual reply off and (3) clearly gets the "I'm not working for you if you don't pay me" message across. Incidentally I had already responded to them in a similar way by the time I saw this answer.

Answer (score 108):

That is polite enough in my opinion. I would make it even shorter.

"I'm sorry but I don't do work on those terms, please let me know if you would like me to provide a quote for the job."

If they don't answer I haven't wasted much time. It clarifies my position and leaves the ball in their court if they want to negotiate.

Comment: +1 Or even "Sorry, I only work for monetary compensation.  If you'd like to me to quote the job for you, I'm happy to do so."

Comment: @JaneS Or just plain "Nooooooope." If this is the opening offer, chances are pretty good it's a toxic client.

Comment: Toxic clients don't worry me, as a freelancer you develop strategies to deal with those and you charge them more to make up for the grief... getting paid is the only real concern

Answer (score 12):

It's unclear to me why so many people are afraid of negotiation and for asking for what they want/deserve.

Quote a price.  Either it will be worth it to them or not.  You don't need to be polite about not accepting an offer, that doesn't necessarily make you rude.  You don't even need to necessarily reference it.

Don't let them set the standards or the options for the value of your work.

I would say something like:

"My price for that work would be $xxx.  Let me know if that works for you!"

Consider this.  If you went to a car dealership and offered a car dealer a few cases of wine for a car, the dealer doesn't have to apologize for not accepting it, they will probably just tell you their price for the car.

Comment: "You don't need to be polite about not accepting an offer." - You do if you still want to get the work but just not for the current offer. Having just bought a new car I'd hazard a bet that your car dealer would politely decline and then tell you the price rather than just tell you their price. I didn't offer wine but I did offer less than he was asking and the response was along the lines of 'I'm sorry, I'd love to give it to you for that price but XYZ stops me, I can do it for...'.

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase.  You shouldn't be rude, but you don't necessarily need to be polite.  This is business, after all.  Some people *will* be polite, and that's also fine.  It isn't required.  And lack of polite statements is not necessarily rudeness.

Comment: @DavidLjungMadison I usually think of polite and rude as opposites, so I'm not actually sure how you are suggesting to behave.

Comment: There's being polite, there's being rude, and then you can simply state facts.  For example, your comment above this one is your response to mine and doesn't contain any polite niceties in it.  It's neither polite or rude.

Comment: There is a problem with this approach.  Since the prospective client claims that the ticket has a dollar value your proposed answer is ambigous.

Comment: I see where you are coming from David but my mum would still disagree with you. :D

Comment: @Taemyr, I completely disagree.

If you do a plumbing job for a client who sells paint and the price quoted is $100, they do *not* get to pay you with $100 worth of paint.  That's not ambiguous.  $100 worth of paint is not $100.

If they are positive their ticket has the same value as $X, then they should have no problem selling it to someone for $X.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should seriously consider bartering as payment for some jobs. I agree barter isn't acceptable for every transaction but sometimes it can lead to surprisingly beneficial outcomes.

In a book I read recently, [The Entrepreneur Mind](http://theentrepreneurmind.com/), one section spoke specifically to working with barter as payment.

The gist of that section is this:

> If you think you can leverage the barter into an outcome that is worth
>   more than the monetary value you would be paid then you should take
>   the barter.

You may have little interest in the ticket but you could sell it, give it to another client/perspective client, or trade it for something else. I admit this takes more effort on your part but if you trade well you can come out ahead.

You also say ticket is free. People are more willing to part with items like tickets, which can be thought of as a  kind of [option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_(finance)), than with money since they see them as possible income rather than immediate loss. Look up [delay discounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_discounting) for a better explanation of the phenomenon. Working with this assumption, you may be able to negotiate for more worth than the client would be willing to pay directly.

Comment: Nothing wrong with barter if there is a clear advantage or if you're doing someone a favour. But in this case there is no clear advantage.

Comment: The only time you should barter is if there is a specific advantage you want to gain. Then you say, "Normally I would charge X, but if you can introduce me to Y then I will do this for free." Or whatever it is that you want down the road (maybe actual *paying* gigs with this company, for instance.)

Comment: It is especially a disadvantage when the unwanted item has a limited shelf life like a ticket. With more tangible items you can potentially barter or sell those to others. With a ticket they will have issues with this especially if the tickets have no resell value, restrictions on resale, or can easily be bought (or bartered in the exchange of services) from the event promoter. The OP has nothing to gain from accepting the ticket.

Comment: +1 you have to be smart about it (negotiate a favorable deal in all cases) but many industries work with a lot of payment "in trade" - I worked for a publishing house and we got a lot of trade-for-advertising deals to the point that we had a whole computer system to manage all the trade-stuff we got in; hotels, restaurants, etc. would often pay like 50% in trade that then our sales force would use when traveling.

Comment: Yes, but those were generally bartering in "value tickets" with a long shelf life. 10.000 USD advertising at going rate usable over 3 years has a value. A ticket for an event in X months has a much lower resale value AND a very short timespan before it turns null and void.

Comment: If you can't complete the project can you refund the used ticket?

Comment: @djechlin, The same problem exists with monetary transactions since you may not be able to refund cash that you have spent. I've seen exactly this situation in federal contracting. In general, I recommend not accepting a job where payment is separate from deliverables or ensuring you can afford the consequences of non-delivery before accepting.

Answer (score 0):

To offer a the other side of the argument, if the event had plenty of potential future clients, I would take the pass, or possibly a cut of the gross, and use the event for grabbing future clients.

Comment: You'd have to be pretty desperate for clients for that to make sense.

Comment: @Casey You've obviously never owned your own business.

Comment: Maybe the wisdom of spending time you could be using for paying clients on someone who doesn't want to pay in the hope that you'll find some other clients later if they're happy with the valuable stuff you gave them for free is a secret you don't learn until you've operated a business.

Comment: @Casey Mind to add a few commas in that?

Comment: @Casey.  I've picked up clients while taking classes, How about you?  Again, as I said in the original answer, I'm posting a counter side.

Comment: But taking classes makes sense, there's the difference.

Answer (score -2):

I would not bother to respond (with anything more than "No.  Thanks.  Be well."

Clients that try to engage in business relationships this will often have other corners they are trying to cut, or otherwise compromise.  Chances are that you will pay more in wasted time, even if they actually pay in cash.

I have had this happen a few times to me, and as well to colleagues and other associates.

I would never recommend it, but if somehow you feel you need to barter, be sure to only accept the [COGS-value](http://www.accountingtools.com/definition-cost-of-goods-sold) for what they are offering.  They are they ones that need to (initiated) barter — they can afford the comp in order to get a nearly-free service that will stimulate more cash-sales (e.g. tickets in this case).

Comment: Not answering the way to go to terminate potential future businesses. E.g., I've contacted many estate agents in the past to find me some object for renting. Quite some of which never replied back, I guess because they focus on buying, not renting. You can guess that I won't have any use for them in case I am looking for buying.

Comment: While the company's offer is not worth spending much time on, a courtesy email takes a minute and is good practice.  Also, if barter does happen, what matters is how much each side values the good being offered, not COGS.

Comment: I agree 100% with the 2nd paragraph, but I have to think that such a client would also bad mouth you for not responding at all.

Comment: @BSMP but someone who does wonky-business has a reputation like that among their contacts — what is their 'bad mouthing' really amount to?  Regardless, I have no objection with the suggestions to offer some courtesy reply.

Comment: @NewAlexandria - They only have a reputation like that among people they've done it to. The folks they pay properly, the friends they don't do business with, and the folks reading the negative review the client leaves on Google don't know that they cut corners. They only know what the client tells them, which will be that the OP stops responding once you start talking about payment.

Comment: You should always be open to different ways of payment. And you should always respond, even if the response is "no thanks".

Comment: @coteyr [not always](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWdd6_ZxX8c); an employer tried to offer me a food perk with my comp, which they valued at $7,000 per year.  They actually were buying fancy food for the team.  Issue is, I did/do really well making very healthy meals on a budget, and I don't spend more than $8-10/day doing that.  I do not need to give up $27/day (at "retail food value") from my salary, when that can go to much-needed debt or necessities.

Answer (score -4):

The number one underlying thing here is how YOU value the service that you're offering.  Potential clients will come and go, and they're going to test you with stuff like this.  It's up to you, with each one, to figure out if the end-result is going to be a win-win situation.

Offering you a ticket for compensation is a test -- no more, no less.  If you're not firm in your resolve, then this potential client learns that you can be strung along and that while you might turn out high quality work, you don't value your time.  And you'll be abused until you get sick of it.

If this potential client really needs your unique services badly enough, then a better offer would be put on the table.  Like the others here have noted, receiving an offer like you have already sets a bad precedent.  You've already been labeled, by the client, as a potential sucker.  But that same client wouldn't try that with, oh, some design firm with a big downtown office somewhere.  Absolutely, do not accept.  But also, give a lot of thought about the impression you're making on potential customers, and adjust yourself so they'll know you're serious (right from the start!) and won't try this kind of stunt.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're shouting about the asker cleaning up their act. What did they do to deserve that?

Comment: Sometimes it can be as subtle as a weak handshake.  Or, the initial consultation gets "steered" by the potential client instead of the consultant.  Or, the consultant *announces* to the prospect that he/she (the consultant) is a student with not much experience.  It's like throwing fresh meat out in front of vultures.  I see this all the time on the Freelancing stackexchange mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the asker has a weak handshake or is letting the initial consultation get steered by the client, or is announcing that they're a noob. By declaring that they should "CLEAN UP [THEIR] ACT", you're being rather insulting to the asker. I gave you the opportunity to retract that insult but, instead, you added three more. That's way, way out of line. You've decided that the asker has certain characteristics, based on zero evidence, and now you're berating them based solely on your unfounded opinion of them.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is so down-voted. Perhaps the voters haven't had much experience working for themselves? I don't know. What I do know is that the situation described here does happen... often. Especially to independents. I have had to terminate my business relationship with many clients because of this type of negotiation. +1 for bringing up a topic the other answers have missed...

Comment: @Cypher That's the conclusion I've come up with.  The downvoters are somebody else's worker-bees.

Answer (score -4):

I'll keep it short and simple, and a little tough.

> Thank you for your offer sir, but we deal in money system rather in Barter system. Please let us know if you are interested in having a project discussion and further getting quotes from us

This might not look gentle enough but is an effective approach to speak up every thing in small words. It will caste an image that you sell your knowledge as per your style not others